# Serverless Framework Error: Every Resources object must contain a Type member

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, amazon-efs

I'm trying to mount an EFS to my Lambda function so that I can use large dependencies. So far I've been following [this](https://www.philschmid.de/mount-your-aws-efs-volume-into-aws-lambda-with-the-serverless-framework) tutorial.

I slightly modified the `.yml`.

#### serverless.yml

```
service: test2EFS

plugins:
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters

custom:
  efsAccessPoint: fsap-00**********
  LocalMountPath: /mnt/efs
  subnetsId: subnet-0b**********
  securityGroup: sg-0b7**********

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  region: us-east-2

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - .vscode/**
    - .serverless/**
    - .pytest_cache/**
    - __pychache__/**

functions:
  test:
    handler: handler.handler
    environment: # Service wide environment variables
      MNT_DIR: ${self:custom.LocalMountPath}
    vpc:
      securityGroupIds:
        - ${self:custom.securityGroup}
      subnetIds:
        - ${self:custom.subnetsId}
    iamManagedPolicies:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonElasticFileSystemClientReadWriteAccess
    events:
      - http:
          path: test
          method: get

resources:
  extensions:
    # Name of function
    test2EFSLambdaFunction:
      Properties:
        FileSystemConfigs:
          - Arn: 'arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:${self:provider.region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:access-point/${self:custom.efsAccessPoint}'
            LocalMountPath: '${self:custom.LocalMountPath}'
```

Whenever I run `severless deploy` I get the following error:

```
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service test2EFS.zip file to S3 (926 B)...
Serverless: Validating template...
 
  Error --------------------------------------------------
 
  Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: [/Resources/test2EFSLambdaFunction] Every Resources object must contain a Type member.
      at provider.request.catch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/deploy/lib/validateTemplate.js:20:13)
      at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
      at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
      at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
      at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
      at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)
      at _drainQueueStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
      at _drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
      at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
      at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
      at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
      at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
      at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)
```

I tried commenting out various parts, and narrowed down the error to somewhere within

```
resources:
  extensions:
    # Name of function
    test2EFSLambdaFunction:
      Properties:
        FileSystemConfigs:
          - Arn: 'arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:${self:provider.region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:access-point/${self:custom.efsAccessPoint}'
            LocalMountPath: '${self:custom.LocalMountPath}'
```

besides renaming (what I think is) an insignificant function name, this code snippet is the same as the reference. I tried hard coding `#{AWS::AccountId}` based on my account ID, but that didn't work. I'm now a bit stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally CloudFormation expects a `Type` parameter in a resource definition, e.g. `Type: AWS::Lambda::Function`, hence why you're seeing the error. In your case you're using the [Override AWS CloudFormation Resource](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources/#override-aws-cloudformation-resource)  functionality by Serverless though, i.e. the name needs to exactly match the normalized function name Serverless assigns (see the doc linked above), in your case this would be `TestLambdaFunction`.

Change your code to:

```
resources:
  extensions:
    TestLambdaFunction:
      Properties:
        [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I talked to some folks on GitHub. As stated by yvesonline, this method overrides auto generated cloud formation code. Serverless has native support for EFS, and it's recommended over the method described in the question.

native EFS in serverless looks something like this; with `fileSystemConfig` existing within the function definition:

```
test:
    handler: handler.test
    environment: # Service wide environment variables
      MNT_DIR: ${self:custom.LocalMountPath}
    vpc:
      securityGroupIds:
        - ${self:custom.securityGroup}
      subnetIds:
        - ${self:custom.subnetsId}
    iamManagedPolicies:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonElasticFileSystemClientReadWriteAccess
    events:
      - http:
          path: test
          method: get
    fileSystemConfig:
      localMountPath: '${self:custom.LocalMountPath}'
      arn: 'arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:${self:provider.region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:access-point/${self:custom.efsAccessPoint}'
```

you can read more about serverless efs configuration [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/#efs-configuration)